# Use Yaru Gnome Shell theme in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes

Yaru repo on Github has a gnome-shell folder

https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/tree/master/gnome-shell

Can we build it and use the Yaru Gnome Shell theme on Ubuntu 18.04 either through `usr/share/themes` or through `.themes` folder ?

If I made it complex, Yaru repo has gnome shell theme folder, will work on 18.04 ? if yes, please tell me how. Thanks.

Comment: Will it be possible for me to build it myself. I try to avoid files that are not verified. Thanks.

Comment: it is possible.. but it creates/ generates files for the version it is madef for.. I mean if the source code is for Ububtu 19.10 the files generated will be for 19.10. the file may or may not work in 18.04

Comment: I see. I will skip it then. Materia's gnome-shell is working great. I am happy with it. Just curious about Yaru, that's all. Thank you :)

Comment: Tried. usr/share/themes/yaru do not have any gnome-shell folder. Should I be looking somewhere else ?

Comment: Where to place it ? Which folder ? Path please. I found a folder " Yaru " with gnome-shell.css and a few other assets inside.  Thanks.

Comment: It worked. I will try using it tomorrow and confirm. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the link https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru says at one part from below quote "Installing from source is not recommended for average usage!"

> Using Yaru on Ubuntu
>
> The Yaru theme suite is installed with Ubuntu 18.10+ by default! No
>   further steps are required to use it.
>
> Installing from source is not recommended for average usage! Using a
>   legacy Yaru/Communitheme version on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic beaver) via
>   snap installation
>
> ```
> Note that for backward compatibility, we kept the name "communitheme" for bionic beaver.
> ```
>
> Only icon and sound updates will be pushed into this version of the theme suite.
>
> These steps only work on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic beaver)! DO NOT install
>   the snap on 18.10+ installations!
>
> Follow these steps in order to install and enable communitheme.
>
> ```
> Install the communitheme snap on 18.04 by installing communitheme in the Ubuntu Software Application or running snap install communitheme.
>
> Restart your computer.
>
> Click on your user, click on the gear icon and select the "Ubuntu with communitheme snap" session from the pop-up, and login.
>
> Now Ubuntu is using the communitheme including the system, applications, icons, sounds and the cursor.
> ```

---

***Installing from Source:***

Tried it with live ISO and running install of Ubuntu 18.04.. In both cases.. It is observed that to build it from source, these packages are required.

`meson` `sassc` `pkg-config` `libglib2.0-dev`

So, Install the required packages with below command.

```
sudo apt install meson sassc pkg-config libglib2.0-dev
```

Download the file from this link https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/archive/master.zip

Extract it.

[image]

[image]

Now create a script named `yaru.sh` with below content in your `$HOME` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/Downloads/yaru-master
mkdir xyz $HOME/YaruBuiltFromSource
meson setup --prefix=$HOME/YaruBuiltFromSource xyz
ninja -C xyz
ninja -C xyz install
```

run the script from your `$HOME` directory with the below command

```
/bin/bash yaru.sh
```

This script creates the required themes namely ICONS,CURSOR, GTK, SHELL, SOUND etc.. in the `$HOME/YaruBuiltFromSource` directory like below.

you can copy them based on your choice (for example for icon theme) to `$HOME/.icons` or `$HOME/.local/share/icons` or `/usr/share/icons` similarly for other themes also

Please note that you need to play tricks with symbolic links for Yaru shell theme..

[image]

[image]

[image]